# New-TextBlock hidden password with wpk module on powershell

Tags: powershell, wpk

I am extremely new to PowerShell tool making so forgive my ignorance. I imported the WPK module and am trying to create a box with multiple fields. One of those fields is a password field but it shows the password as it's being typed. I am unsure of how to make it so that while typing the text is hidden.

```
      New-TextBlock -Text "Database Login Name" `
        -Row 2 -Column 0 -VerticalAlignment Center -Margin 5        

      New-TextBox -Name DbLoginId  `
        -Row 2 -Column 1 -Margin 4 

      New-TextBlock -Text "Db Login Password" `
        -Row 3 -Column 0 -VerticalAlignment Center -Margin 5        

      New-TextBox -Name DbLoginPassword  `
        -Row 3 -Column 1 -Margin 4
```

Just a heads up, I am not a programmer what so ever. I am a Database Administrator but I have been thrown into this development project so I am literally learning on the fly right about now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your password `TextBox` to a [PasswordBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
  New-PasswordBox -Name DbLoginPassword  `
    -Row 3 -Column 1 -Margin 4
```

Comment: I cannot believe it was that easy! All the google searches I have done never once mentioned that PasswordBox actually existed in WPK. Thank You!

Comment: No problem! If you want to see all of the CmdLets included with WPK, you can use: `gcm -Module WPK| ogv` The filter at the top of the window that opens is useful for narrowing down the results.